# Dump Arangodb database with Go

Tags: go, arangodb

I would like to know if I can dump an ArangoDB with Go.
I know how to use ArangoDB Go driver but there is no example which show how to dump the db.

I also aware about how to download the database on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the arangodump and arangorestore tools provided by ArangoDB to dump and restore a database.

If needed, call those executables from Go.

ArangoDump: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangodump.html

ArangoRestore: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangorestore.html

Comment: I will call those executables from Go.
Thank you for your help